# Where can I find "Device" file to add to EclipseME java project?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I installed JavaME and EclipseME, and I'm trying to make a Hello World to my Nokia5530. But the imports are not working.

[This page](http://www.eclipseme.org/docs/advDeviceMgmt.html) says that I need a "Device" file, but I don't know where to find it.. any idea?

Comment: Try here: http://www.eclipseme.org/docs/advDeviceMgmt.html

Comment: @James Black this is the page I already linked.. ;) It teaches how to import, but don't have a device to import... :(

Comment: OK, you need to install the Nokia SDK and then import it, as explained here, though your phone may not be series 60, you will need to d/l and then import the appropriate nokia sdk version. http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Installing_Java_ME_development_tools_for_S60#Configuring_EclipseME

Comment: @James Black I've downloaded the sdk, but looks like is just for Windows. I'm on Ubuntu 9.10. In [this page](http://developer.symbian.org/main/tools_and_kits/symbian3_developer/index.php) there is a version for Linux, but looks like it's not the same thing, as this file have 100mb, instead of 700mb like the first one... Do you know about linux instructions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears no on else is helping with this, I will start an answer, and put in my last comment into here.

OK, you need to install the Nokia SDK and then import it, as explained here, though your phone may not be series 60, you will need to d/l and then import the appropriate nokia sdk version: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Installing_Java_ME_development_tools_for_S60#Configuring_EclipseME

I haven't tried the suggestions here as I primarily develop on Windows at the moment, but the idea of using wine to install the SDK, and then move the files to an appropriate place on Linux sounds like a reasonable suggestion.  I don't know if the suggestion below of compiling it yourself would be useful, but, there were some suggestions in the link below that may help you solve this particular problem.
http://www.wirelessforums.org/alt-cellular-nokia/nokia-sdk-linux-8895.html